# how to add one day to sql date?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, hql

i wanto get the trip which is happened between contractStartdate and contractEndDate+1day. but this following code gives me error.

```
def tripsForThisContract =  Trip.executeQuery("From Trip where contract_id = ? AND startDate between ? AND DATE_ADD('?',INTERVAL 1 DAY)",[contractId,contractStarts,contractEnds])
```

please help me.

Comment: Can you show the error and the generated query ?

Comment: [2011-06-11 14:08:59:937] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.PARSER ### line 1:112: unexpected token: 1
[2011-06-11 14:08:59:953] ERROR groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver ### unexpected token: 1 near line 1, column 112 [From com.springpeople.steer.trips.Trip where contract_id = ? AND startDate between ? AND DATE_ADD('?',INTERVAL 1 DAY)]
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 1 near line 1, column 112 [From com.springpeople.steer.trips.Trip where contract_id = ? AND startDate between ? AND DATE_ADD('?',INTERVAL 1 DAY)]
 at $Proxy12.createQuery(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should deal with the date inside your code. Hql has not all the functions of the underlying database.

Your code should be something like this :

```
Trip.executeQuery(
"From Trip where contract_id = ? AND startDate between ? AND ?)"
,[contractId,contractStarts, ++contractStarts])
```